# Laravel Need To Filter by Data Where Data Is In A Different Format

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i am using Laravel, In my controller
I need to filter some of my appointments with todays date
Problem is the scheduling of appointment is done through https://acuityscheduling.com/ , so it reporeduce n with a diffrent format
Dump and die

```
{#1763 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => {#1789 ▼
      +"id": "81a99310-4e5a-11eb-b9c9-339354e859f6"
      +"first_name": "s"
      +"phone": "444444444444"
      +"email": "ooo@gmail.com"
      +"status_code": "200"
      +"state": 3
      +"preference": "{"userinfo": {"age": "32", "dob": "1988-01-28", "dob_": {"day": "28", "year": "1988", "month": "01"}, "town": "s", "email": "ooo@gmail.com", "fname": "s", "lnam ▶"
      +"user_id": "81a99310-4e5a-11eb-b9c9-339354e859f6"
      +"created_at": "2021-01-04 07:00:19"
      +"updated_at": "2021-01-04 07:00:19"
      +"response": "{"id": 501222114, "date": "January 20, 2021", "paid": "no", "time": "11:00am", "type": "Evaluation", "email": "ooo@gmail.com", "forms": [{"id": 1584761, "name": ▶"
      +"nhs_number": ""
      +"invitation_id": "exx-103-9"
      +"name": "s"
      +"?column?": "January 20, 2021"
      +"useid": "81a99310-4e5a-11eb-b9c9-339354e859f6"
      +"app_id": "81adbf70-4e5a-11eb-9eac-6143f542e0db"
      +"app_data": "January 20, 2021"
    }
    1 => {#1794 ▶}
    2 => {#1790 ▶}
    3 => {#1788 ▶}
    4 => {#1536 ▶}
    5 => {#1791 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I have used this code to filter

````
                else if($filter == 'today')
                {
                  $appointments = $appointments->where('appointments.app_data', '>=', date('d-m- 
                  Y').' 00:00:00');
                  dd($appointments->get());

                }
    ```

Date format comes like this "app_data": "January 20, 2021"
Can i filter only todays appointment

Thank you
````

Comment: You can get todays date with the same format as your appointment with `date("F j, Y")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution hope it will help. Since your date format stored in database is " January 20, 2021 " so first you need to convert that string to date format in mysql.

```
$appointments = $appointments->where(DB::raw('date_format(str_to_date(appointments.app_data,"%d %M,%Y"),"%Y-%m-%d")'));
```

And Specifically for today you can do something like this:

```
->where(DB::raw('date_format(str_to_date(appointments.app_data,"%d %M,%Y"),"%Y-%m-%d") = CURDATE()'))
```